# Using "celui" or "celle" with adjective

Tags: pronoms, adjectifs

Can we use "celui" or "celle" etc. with an adjective, as in the following examples?

> Le livre rouge est plus intéressant que celui bleu.
>
> La cuisine parisienne est aussi délicieuse que celle bordelaise.

Comment: No, just like in English. The red book is more interesting than that one which is blue. And not: than that one blue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not possible. *Celui* is used as a "*[pronom démonstratif](http://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-2922.php)*", meaning that you cannot use it as a "*[article défini](http://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-30336.php)*" (*le, la, les*), which is what you need in your sentence.

> Le livre rouge est plus intéressant que ***le*** bleu.
>
> La cuisine parisienne est aussi délicieuse que ***la*** bordelaise.

*Celui*, or any other demonstrative pronoun, is meant to replace the subjects it refers to instead of repeating it again.

> Je ne trouvais pas de *crayon*, j'ai donc pris ***celui*** de mon voisin.

---

An alternative to what you're trying to say with the use of *celui* would be (as Lambie pointed out rightly) :

> Le livre rouge est plus intéressant que celui *qui est* bleu.

This is technically "correct", but a bit wonky.